# How to map Array of Dictionaries by using object mapper Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, api, dictionary

Hi I write the model class by using Object mapper like this.

Here I getting the response in Array of Dictionary format.

How to we map the response in this situation please find my code bellow.

```
class Modelclass : Mappable{

    var mainsite : [Mainsite]!

    required init?(map: Map) { }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        mainsite    <- map["Mainsite"]
    }
}


class Mainsite : Mappable{

    var categoryId : String!
    var cPath : String!
    var level : Int!
    var name : String!
    var parentID : String!
    var subItems : [SubItem]!

    required init?(map: Map) { }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        categoryId    <- map["CategoryId"]
        cPath    <- map["cPath"]
        level    <- map["level"]
        name    <- map["Name"]
        parentID    <- map["ParentID"]
        subItems    <- map["SubItems"]
    }
}
```

Here I am trying to map the response with the follow code.

```
    func ApiResponse(){
    Alamofire.request("https://www.furnitureinfashion.net/menu_category.php", method: .get, parameters: nil, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in

        if response.data != nil
        {
            let data = Mapper<Modelclass>().map(JSON: response)

        }else{
            print(response.error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend you to use Codable instead of third part mapping library. https://medium.com/xcblog/painless-json-parsing-with-swift-codable-2c0beaeb21c1

Comment: Post your sample json data

Answer (score 0):

it would be a lot much easier if you shared your response here is well. I am assuming you are getting array of Mainsite object

```
 if response.data != nil
    {
        let data = Mapper<Mainsite>().map(JSONArray: response)

    }
```

if the object you are getting is array of Mainsite Model , then you can use ObjectMapper's map JSON Array Method. it takes input in two forms , 1 is AnyObject, other is [[String  : Any]] , and it will return the array of the Mainsite Model